# How to print/display the output of a telnet session in terminal window (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal

Can someone help to understand how print in the terminal window works?
Here is a test script

test_script.py

```
import telnetlib
HOST = "10.1.1.151"
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
tn.open(HOST)
test_var = ["test"]
print test_var
tn_read =  tn.read_very_eager()
print tn_read
```

Output when script is run from terminal:

```
$ python test_script.py
  ['test']
```

`tn_read` should be something like "User Name : " but it is not printed in the terminal window.

If I run it from the interpreter I get what is expected:

```
 >>> tn.read_very_eager()
 '\n\rUser Name : '
```

Why or what needs to be done to have the following output when the script is called from the terminal ?

```
 $ python test_script.py
  ['test']
  User Name :
```

Comment: the existance of the "\r" in the value makes me wonder if it is worth using .lstrip() on the tn_read variable : i.e. does print tn_read.lstrip() make things better.

Comment: @Tony: No, it does not make any difference.

Comment: @flamenco Perhaps look in the documentation if there are other functions like possibly some `tn.read_not_so_eager()` (just an example), or something like `tn.read()`.

Comment: @Pascal: I tried different functions (`tn.read_unitl(), read_eager()`) but none help to see the values when I run the script from the terminal.

Comment: print should work fine to terminal.   try something like print type(tn_read), tn_read   to figure out if the module is returning the expected result.  if it returns an object enstead of string, maybe you need to change it to string representation first.

Comment: `>>> tn.open(HOST)
>>> tn_read = tn.read_very_eager()
>>> type(tn_read), tn_read
(<type 'str'>, '\n\rUser Name : ')`
>>>

Comment: The modified script: `test_var = ["test"]
print test_var
tn_read =  tn.read_very_eager()
print type(tn_read), tn_read` Output on the terminal: `$ python test_script.py   ['test'] <type 'str'> . "User Name : " is not printed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is to use `read_until()` with a timeout. e.g.

```
timeout = 3    # seconds
tn_read = tn.read_until('User Name :', timeout)
print repr(tn_read)
```

The long answer follows.

`read_very_eager()` is non-blocking and it will return any cooked data already available, but nothing if there isn't any data. If you call a non-blocking "read" method too soon after establishing the connection, there may be no data to read and `read_very_eager()` will return an empty string - `''`.

So your problem is probably timing related; the read is non-blocking and can not return data that has not yet been received, processed, and buffered. When you interact via the terminal, it takes time for you to type in the commands, so you don't notice the timing issue, but when run from a script the human delay is removed, and the timing issue becomes apparent. Try sleeping before calling the read method:

```
import telnetlib
import time

HOST = "10.1.1.151"
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
test_var = ["test"]
print test_var
time.sleep(5)
tn_read =  tn.read_very_eager()
print repr(tn_read)
```

Run the above as a script and you *might* see your expected output.... then again, you might not. Instead you might still see:

```
['test']
''
```

There may be other factors too, in particular the server may be responding with a Telnet IAC sequence. `telnetlib` will consume this sequence if it has arrived before you call `read_very_eager()` (any read function actually). In this case `read_very_eager()` also returns an empty string.

If you want to see what is being exchanged over the connection, you can call `set_debuglevel(1)`:

import telnetlib

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet('library.cedarville.edu')   # any old server will do
tn.set_debuglevel(1)
tn_read =  tn.read_all()
print repr(tn_read)
```

Typical output is:

```
Telnet(library.cedarville.edu,23): recv '\xff\xfd\x03'
Telnet(library.cedarville.edu,23): IAC DO 3
Telnet(library.cedarville.edu,23): recv '\xff\xfb\x03\xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfd\x18\xff\xfd#\xff\xfd$\xff\xfd\x1f'
Telnet(library.cedarville.edu,23): IAC WILL 3
Telnet(library.cedarville.edu,23): IAC WILL 1
Telnet(library.cedarville.edu,23): IAC DO 24
Telnet(library.cedarville.edu,23): IAC DO 35
Telnet(library.cedarville.edu,23): IAC DO 36
Telnet(library.cedarville.edu,23): IAC DO 31
Telnet(library.cedarville.edu,23): recv '\r\n'
Telnet(library.cedarville.edu,23): recv 'login: '
```

Of the other "read" functions, you should probably use `read_until()`. If you don't want to block indefinitely, pass a timeout to it as shown above.

Comment: it was timing related when using `read_very_eager`!  you saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Example of a telnet session on a terminal of a networking gear:

```
HOST = "1.1.1.1"
PORT = 30001
TIMEOUT = 3
PASSWD = "cisco"
COMMANDS = ["term len 0","show version","show ip route","show run","!!!end!!!"]

import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT, TIMEOUT)
#tn.set_debuglevel(1)
tn.write("\r\n\r\n")
for cmd in COMMANDS:
    tn.write(cmd+"\r\n")

print tn.read_until("!!!end!!!\r\n",3)
tn.close()
```